# Manipulate two MySQL tables and get third table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

order_master

```
order_id, name, address
1, Andy, Hong Kong
2, Sandy, NYT
```

order_child

```
item_id, order_id, no_of_parcels, qty
1, 1, 1, abc book, 3
2, 1, 1, sss book, 5
3, 2, 1, jj book, 2
4, 2, 1, aa book, 3
```

Now I want to combine above two tables using PHP and MySQL to get third table on my web page.

order

```
order_id, name, no_of_parcels, description, qty
1, Andy, 2, (abc book, sss book), 8
2, Sandy, 2, (jj book, aa book), 5
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried any MySQL? Post what you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You perform aggregation to find sums and group_concats and then, join it with the master table:

```
select *
from order_master m
join (
    select order_id,
        sum(num_of_parcels) num_of_parcels,
        group_concat(description order by item_id separator ', ') description,
        sum(qty) qty
    from order_child
    group by order_id
    ) c
    on m.order_id = c.order_id;
```

If you want to do this without subquery:

```
select m.order_id,
    m.name,
    m.address,
    sum(c.num_of_parcels) num_of_parcels,
    group_concat(c.description order by c.item_id separator ', ') description,
    sum(c.qty) qty
from order_master m
join order_child c
    on m.order_id = c.order_id
group by m.order_id,
    m.name,
    m.address,
```